# Circular Loop with Xamarin Android deep linking

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I am currently implementing the deeplinking in our eCommerce Xamarin app.
There are some pages that are not mapped yet in the app. These pages should be ignored and open in the browser. As this is not possible in Android (there is no exclude possible as far as I know), I thought that I could do it as this:

1. I open a link, e.g. [www.exampleshop.com/Help](http://www.exampleshop.com/Help)
2. Our app is opened, make a call to our API and see, that there is no app page for that link existing.
3. So it will redirect back to the Browser, either with the In-App browser or externally with the system installed browser.

The behavior is, that in both cases it redirects again to the app, so that we are now in an endless loop.

Is there any way to break out from that loop?

Thanks in advance,
Dennis

Comment: You can check this document about [App-Linking in Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking). You might misunderstand the deep linking. Deep-Linking allows a mobile device to respond to a URI and launch a mobile application that corresponds to that URI.

Comment: Hi Guangyu, 
I read that document already, but couldn't find an answer to my question. I know what the deeplinking does, maybe I didn't explained my problem correctly. Our webshop have plenty of subpages like categories, product detail pages, help section, user area, etc. Some of them doesn't exist yet in the mobile app so that they should be opened as before in the browser. As there is no possibility to exclude urls in android, my idea was to redirect to the app for all urls and then check if an equivalent app page exists or not. If not, then redirect back to the browser.

Comment: It is recommended that you can give the user the choices, and the user can choose to open the product page in the app or continue browsing on the webpage. This shows more respect to the users. If some pages do not exist in the mobile app, you can show them directly on webpage and do not need to redirect to the mobile app and detect.